# EF related entities, tried to insert related ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two related tables **Order** and **OrderItem**.  I need EF to insert the related id from the Order table to the OrderItem.

I have listed my models Order and Orderitem just en case, i think the relation is done right.

But i dont know how, i am new to Entityframework. So i need a little help :0)

```
 public ActionResult Accept(Order order)
    {

        order.orderDetails = new List<OrderItem>();
        var cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];

        var ord = new Order()
        {

            firstName = order.firstName,
            lastName = order.lastName,
            Email = order.Email,
            phone = order.phone,
            postalCode = order.postalCode,
            city = order.city
        };

        foreach (var item in cart)
        {

            var itemOrder = new OrderItem
            {

                orderName = item.Product.productName,
                salePrice = item.Product.consignment.salePrice,
                quantity = item.Quantity,

            };



            order.orderDetails.Add(itemOrder);

            db.Orders.Add(ord);

            // db.OrderItems.Add(itemOrder);







        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

Models

**Order**

```
public partial class Order
{
    public int orderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? orderDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Ordre detaljer")]
    public string orderText { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Fornavn")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Efternavn")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("E-mail adresse")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Telefon nr")]
    public string phone { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Postnr")]
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("By")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    public List<OrderItem> orderDetails;

    public Order()
    {
        orderDetails = new List<OrderItem>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> orderItems { get; set; }

}
```

**Orderitem**

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public int orderItemId { get; set; }
    public string orderName { get; set; }
    public float salePrice { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("orderId")]
    //public virtual Order Order { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, if you are creating a new `Order` the context has no idea of its existence, so `db.Entry(order)` is not going to fly

Comment: How do you generate your id & what type?

Comment: No i was just trying somethink. :0)

Answer (score 0):

Don't manually add the order item into `db.OrderItems`. Assuming the order's "OrderDetails" property that you are using is mapped (through EF) to the OrderItem table, adding the item to the orderDetails collection should be enough to insert the record with the correct foreign key to `Order`.

Comment: should i remove some of this lines?


                db.Orders.Add(ord);
                order.orderDetails.Add(itemOrder);
                db.OrderItems.Add(itemOrder);

Comment: just the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You are in correct way just fix like below :

You need to add `items` to each `order` first

```
var ord = new Order()
    {
         ...
    };
foreach (var item in cart)
{
    var itemOrder = new OrderItem
    {
         ...
     };
   order.orderDetails.Add(itemOrder);
}
db.Orders.Add(ord);
```

Comment: Do you mean the item var from the foreach loop? :0)

Comment: It is `ItemOrder` .First add ItemOrders of each order

Comment: Like this?

         order.orderDetails.Add(itemOrder);
                db.Orders.Add(itemOrder);

Comment: It didnt work,  i have edited my question. maybe the relation is wrong between Order and OrderItem. I dont know :0)

Comment: What happened?are you got error ?if not , does order saved in db ?

Comment: I don't know code first . But do you set [Key] attribute for id in two tables and [ForeignKey("orderId")] is in comment

Comment: It have the order, but not orderItem. I will try to add the key attibute maybe this works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Thank you guys for your help anyway :0)

the solution was to add the following line:

```
 public ActionResult Accept(Order order)
        {
 
            order.orderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
            var cart = (List<Item>)Session["cart"];

        
            foreach (var item in cart)
            {
                    var ord = new Order()
            {
             
                firstName = order.firstName,
                lastName = order.lastName,
                Email = order.Email,
                phone = order.phone,
                postalCode = order.postalCode,
                city = order.city
            };


                var itemOrder = new OrderItem
                {
                
                    orderName = item.Product.productName,
                    salePrice = item.Product.consignment.salePrice,
                    quantity = item.Quantity,
        
                };
```

> ```
>        ((List<OrderItem>)order.orderItems).Add(itemOrder);
> ```

```
            }

            db.Orders.Add(order);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
```